# iPhone error "NsUrlConnetionInternalConnection_WithConnectionDisconnectFromConnection"

Tags: iphone

We are getting an error:

> [NsUrlConnetionInternalConnection_WithConnectionDisconnectFromConnection]:
>   message send to deallocated instance 0*7a58e60  while runnting an
>   iPhone application.

It is using a live webservice. But it is working with locally created webservice. Please give us a solution to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've deallocated an instance of `NSURLConnection` that is still in use. Try using the Zombies instrument in Instruments to find the memory management history of the object and where you're breaking it.